# In mule how will I transform with dynamic parent values

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
Input:    
{    
"2019-02-17":[    
{    
"date":"2019-02-17",    
 "address":"ap",    
"city":"vijayawada"    
}    
],    
"2019-02-18":[    
{    
"date":"2019-02-18",    
"address":"west bengal",    
"city":"kolkata"    
 },
{    
"date":"2019-02-18",    
"address":"tamil Nadu",    
"city":"chennai"    
 }    
]    
} 

 Output:
 To be transformed to        
{    
"Address":[    
{    
"date":"2019-02-17",    
 "address":"ap"    
 },    
{     
"date":"2019-02-18",    
"address":"west bengal"    
},
{     
"date":"2019-02-18",    
"address":"tamil nadu"    
}
]    
 }
```

How do I transform with the help of dynamic parent keys. Trying to transform with the help of mapObject but getting the fields as array of string format

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your expected output by using Pluck operator. Please find the below code.

```html
    %dw 2.0
output application/json  
---

  address: (payload pluck $) flatMap $ map (item, index) -> {
    date: item.date,
    address: item.address
  }
```

Thanks,

Manish Yadav